# Как сделать привязку параметров (binding) при Update для Yii2?

Tags: sql, yii2, binding, update

Yii2, обновление нескольких строк:

```
    $sql = 'UPDATE category SET 
        parent = CASE id 
            WHEN 1 THEN 0 
            WHEN 2 THEN 1 
            ELSE parent 
        END, 
        title = CASE id 
            WHEN 1 THEN "строка 1" 
            WHEN 2 THEN "строка 2" 
            ELSE title 
        END
        WHERE id IN (1, 2)
        AND user_id = 15';

    Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)
        ->execute();
```

Задача - сделать `binding` параметров. Во множестве примеров документации вижу способы привязки для select-запросов, и ни одного способа/примера для update-запроса.

Данные от клиента приходят в виде массива JSON-объектов `[{"id":1,"user_id":15,"parent":0,"title":"строка"},{"id":2,"user_id":15,"parent":1,"title":"строка 1"}]`, версия MySql - 8.0.18.0

Контроллер:

```
public function actionSaveCategory()
{
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        $request = Yii::$app->request->post('categories');           
        
        $categories = json_decode($request, true);
        $model = new Category;
        $rows = [];

        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $model->load($category, '');
            $model->id = $category['id'];

            if (!$model->validate()) {
                return 'error';
            }

            $rows[] = $model->attributes;
    };
}
```

Знаю о существовании `batchInsert ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, но здесь данные поступают от клиента и мне нужно делать проверку: `AND user_id = 15`

Прошу совета, можно ли сделать **binding** для **update**, и как это сделать.

Comment: Я верно понимаю, что обновляется синхронно строго две записи? или от клиента может прийти исходник для обновления сотни записей сразу?

Comment: здесь могут быть сотни записей на обновление одним запросом

Comment: Тогда - точная версия MySQL?

Comment: да, сейчас я фактически повторил один в один MySQL-запрос, но у меня большие сомнения в безопасности такого решения. Данные предварительно проходят валидацию, но этого может быть недостаточно, как я предполагаю.

Comment: *у меня большие сомнения в безопасности такого решения* Обоснуйте. Или Вы имеете в виду, что пакет изменений - согласованный, и его частичное выполнение может порушить внешнюю целостность данных? И всё же - версия сервера какая?

Comment: я недостаточно компетентен, чтобы быть уверенным, что не получу sql-инъекцию. Это одна из причин, по которой задаю вопрос. О целостности данных пока не думал, но эта проблема, насколько я понимаю, решается оборачиванием в транзакцию. Yii2 - 2.0.14. MySQL Server 8.0

Comment: SQL-инъекция - следствие не проблемного текста запроса, а метода прямой подстановки параметров в него.

Comment: а если вместо текста "строка 1" от клиента придет что-то другое?

Comment: Так тестируйте, что он там наводил... прежде чем бросаться выполнять запрос. И желательно на стороне сервера в том числе.

Comment: ок. Правильно ли я понимаю, что binding как таковой тут сделать нельзя?

Comment: В какой точно форме приходят данные от клиента? Можно ли его преобразовать в массив JSON-объектов `[{"id":1,"parent":0,"title":"строка 1"},{"id":2,"parent":1,"title":"строка 2"}]` и именно в такой форме передать в запрос? И какая ТОЧНО версия MySQL?

Comment: именно в таком виде и приходят, версия 8.0.18.0, добавил эту информацию в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> версия 8.0.18

Это будет что-то вроде

```sql
UPDATE category,
       ( SELECT id, parent, title
         FROM JSON_TABLE(@parameter,
                         "$[*]" COLUMNS( id INT PATH "$.id",
                                         parent INT PATH "$.parent",
                                         title TEXT PATH "$.title" )
                        ) AS jsontable
       ) AS newdata
SET category.parent = newdata.parent,
    category.title = newdata.title
WHERE category.id = newdata.id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=78b6f8d6026d8c6f988cf746d5be65a9)

Comment: спасибо! такой запрос до тысячи строк будет оптимальным по сравнению с любыми другими способами обновления данных?

Comment: Конечно. Одним пакетом передали, и пусть сервер пыхтит - а он в памяти всё это сразу обработает куда как быстрее, чем туда-сюда через сокеты байты гонять. Только дополнительный совет - предварительно проверьте JSON на валидность. Вплоть до добавления `... AND JSON_VALID(@parameter)` в текст запроса. Потому что при невалидном JSON запрос НЕ даст ошибки - просто ни фига не обновит, и всё.